# Do not allow special characters in NumericUpDown EditorFor() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to display a NumericUpDown control based on my property (int). It works but it allows me to enter special characters like #$%&..

My .cshtml code is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SerialAddress, "MyControlName")
```

My property in my model is:

```
[Required]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof (WebResources), Name = WebResources.LabelAddress)]
public int SerialAddress { get; set; }
```

How can I do this? My property is a int but the control allow me to write #$%&

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set model property as

if you want no's only as your property is int.

```
[Required]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof (WebResources), Name = WebResources.LabelAddress)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]\d+$", ErrorMessage = "invalid character")]
public int SerialAddress { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
[Required]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof (WebResources), Name = WebResources.LabelAddress)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Numeric Only")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = “Enter Numeric only”)]

public int SerialAddress { get; set; }
```